# Can I make a script for a macro to change volume?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm planning on getting a desktop computer soon, and the keyboard I selected has no volume up down keys.  I'll miss this from my laptop, so can I use AutoHotKey to change that?  From the command list, it doesn't look like it.  On the keyboard I've chosen I'd like it to be \F12:: SetVolumeUp

or something like that.

I don't think it's possible, is it?

Answer (score 7):

Yes this is possible. You want to look at the `SoundSet` command:

```
SoundSet, 50  ; Set the master volume to 50%
SoundSet +10  ; Increase master volume by 10%
SoundSet -10  ; Decrease master volume by 10%
```

See http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm

You can also use just the `Send` command to simulate keystrokes like this:

```
Send {Volume_Up}  ; Raise the master volume by 1 interval (typically 5%).
Send {Volume_Down 3}  ; Lower the master volume by 3 intervals.
Send {Volume_Mute}  ; Mute/unmute the master volume.
```

See http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Here is an example of a script that remaps the F10-F12 keys to control volume:

```
;F10
^F10::
    SendInput, {F10}
    Return

$F10::Send {Volume_Mute}

;F11
^F11::
    SendInput, {F11}
    Return

$F11::Send {Volume_Down 5}

;F12
^F12::
    SendInput, {F12}
    Return

$F12::Send {Volume_Up 5}
```

See http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/62808-remap-f10-f11-f12/

Comment: I'm having the specific problem of setting the \ key to a script...  I've tried its hex value, 02B, and nothing is working.  

Using the easier method, this is my script.

SC02BF10::Send {Volume_Up}

Comment: I don't think you can use \ as a modifier key for F12. See http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm for a list of modifiers that are supported, \ is not listed on that page.

Comment: Assuming that your Fx keys work without the use of the Fn key and you want to combine \ and F10, then use \ & F10::  AND add \::Sendinput,\ to restore the \ key.

Comment: @jszobody, `Send {Volume_Up}` and `Send {Volume_Down}` these keys moves a bit the webpage also if I'm changing volume when my mouse is in a browser? Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to set F1 to F8 as media and volume controls. Try using Crimson Editor to create the script:

;stop
+F1::
Send {Volume_Down}
return

;stop
+F2::
Send {Volume_Up}
return

;stop
+F3::
Send {Volume_Mute}
return

;next song
+F7:: ;the + means shift
Send {Media_Next}
return

;previous song
+F6::
Send {Media_Prev}
return

;play/pause
+F5::
Send {Media_Play_Pause}
return

;stop
+F8::
Send {Media_Stop}
return

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered, but I have a nice function that I use:
Since I use <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> for controlling the magnifyer in Photoshop, I thought it would be easy for me to remember those keys for the volume.

Here I use the <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to lower the volume and
<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to raise the volume.

Here I use the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to set it to a comfortable minimum level and
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to set it to a comfortable loud level (for movies).

After it adjusts the volume it will play a simple beep sound so you can see just how loud it is.

```
;sound controls
#[::setVolume("-10")        ;lower volume by 10%
#]::setVolume("+10")        ;raise volume by 10%
^#[::setVolume("10")        ;set volume to minimum
^#]::setVolume("80")        ;set volume to loud

SetVolume(whatvolume){
    soundset, %whatvolume%
    soundplay, *-1
}
```